# Tortoise-Hg (mercurial) does not find hg-git

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have Tortoise Hg installed on my Windows box, and have been using mercurial via the Tortoise GUI and also from the windows commandline. I installed hg-git as recommended on http://hg-git.github.com/ : Using `easy_install hg-git`, which built the package with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008. There were no error messages and the build reported success.

I then added the extension to the configuration file. But TortoiseHg still doesn't accept git urls, and when I run hg from the commandline, I get:

```
*** failed to import extension hggit: No module named hggit
```

Now, python does know about hggit and will find it if I type `import hggit` at the interpreter (it fails when hggit tries to import mercurial). I understand that TortoiseHg provides it own python environment, so my question is: How do I install hggit so that it is visible to the tortoise-distributed mercurial? Or am I misdiagnosing the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How did you reference the extension in the `.hgrc` file ?

If you just did

```
[extensions]
hggit=
```

Try adding the complete path to the extension :

```
[extensions]
hggit = [path-to]/hg-git/hggit
```

This should tell TortoiseHg exactly where to look and bypass any difference of configuration between the command line and the gui.

Comment: That was it, thanks! There was an additional complication because easy_install only installed hg_git as an egg, which mercurial won't accept for some reason. So I opened it with a ZIP archiver and extracted the hggit folder. (I'm sure there's an easy_install option for that, but it was more trouble to look it up). Still needed the full path as well, as you suggested.